# As a whole I am intense desire

Tags: riddle, word

> As a whole, I am intense desire.
>   Behead me, and I accommodate children.
>   Behead me again, and I accommodate animals.
>   Restore me, and I become fire.

What am I?

(An original riddle)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you are

> Spark

As a whole, I am intense desire.

> **Spark** can be used to describe an intense feeling, especially emotionally towards another person.

Behead me, and I accommodate children.

> **Park** - where children can play

Behead me again, and I accommodate animals.

> **Ark** - as in Noah's Ark.

Restore me, and I become fire.

> A **spark** can be used to start a fire.